# saving user state in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Update - this question was originally not about session states.

I am trying to change a variable in the user state in MVC 5

```
// POST: /Account/Registered
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Registered(loggedinViewModel model, ApplicationUser user, string selcteditem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new UserDb()));                
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new UserDb());
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var newCID = clubIDMethod();

        var ctx = store.Context as UserDb;

        ctx.Users.Attach(user);

        SelectedNewCID(model, newCID);

        ViewBag.newCID = (model.SelectedGodCID);

        user.CID = ViewBag.newCID;

        currentUser.CID = user.CID;                

    }
    return View(model);  
}
```

I am really unsure what the state is not being saved,  the `currentUser.CID` is being updated but then when I go else where it's still set to the original value

Please Help Thanks

Comment: You aren't saving your changes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx.

Comment: ctx.SaveChanges(); fails and also that would save back to the DB yes? set something to be something different, but not save it back to the db

Comment: Where is the _elsewhere_ that you are referencing in your question? Because your controller method is pretty much the beginning and end of the user code portion of the web request/response life cycle.

Comment: other controllers / views  
the error from save changes is this Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: like for instance when, currentUser.CID = user.CID; changes its ok on this but as soon as I move away from this class the variable changes back to the original value

Comment: Everything goes away after the response is sent to the web browser, so if you aren't persisting your data, then you won't see it again on the next web request.

Comment: @KeithPayne ok so this leads back to my question, how do i save that to the CID variable?

Comment: To save it, you have to call `SaveChanges()`. What does the EntityValidationErrors property say about the validation error(s)?

Comment: how do obtain the EntityValidationErrors I can not find this anywhere to set a brake-point on it

Comment: actually if I remove the line, ctx.Users.Attach(user); this go's away but the ID isn't updated even when calling SaveChanges()

Comment: and i am not wanting to save it back to the database

Comment: How is `currentUser` declared? Do you understand a new controller is instantiated for each request? Have you heard of session?

Comment: currentUser is obtain for the database, and then set in the identityModels.cs, this is the first time I am needing to update it, and yes I understand a new controller is instantiated per request, I could use a session variable but not sure how in MVC 5 :( please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a Session on global.aspx with something like this

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = string.Empty;
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionItem", temp);
    }
```

and then you need to assign that the CID with something like this

```
Session["_SessionItem"] = ViewBag.newCID;
```

this will hold the string in a session.

you need to then read that in using the session.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed Thanks Mike